# Array Pointer Returns Garbage

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to subtract two integers of the same size without using an explicit loop using `valarray`.
For this purpose I've written a function i.e `subtract(int *firstarray, int *secondarray)`. However, the subtraction occurs correctly in function as printed out. But when returned to `main()` the first two values of array contain garbage. **What is my mistake**?

```
int* subtract(int* lastline, int* firstline){// takes two user defined arrays and performs subtraction

    std::valarray<int> foo (firstline, 7);  //  6 6 5 4 5 6 7
    std::valarray<int> bar (lastline,7);    //  1 8 8 8 8 8 8
    std::valarray<int> res (7);

    res=bar-foo; //subtracts two valarrays

    for (size_t i=0; i<NUMBEROFCLASSES;i++){
        cout<<res[i]<<" ";                  //prints 5 -2 -3 -4 -3 -2 -1
   }

    return &res[0];
}


int main(){

int first[7]={6,6,5,4,5,6,7};
int second[7]={1,8,8,8,8,8,8};
int *e= subtract(first, second);
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<7;i++){
    cout<<e[i]<<" ";                       // prints 0 0 -3 -4 -3 -2 -1
    }
return 1;
}
```

Comment: The local objects will be destroyed when get ouf of the function; the returned pointer becomes dangled.

Comment: res is a local variable it is gone after the call to subtract(). You can't return a pointer to a local.

Comment: Please [read a couple of good beginner books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Learn about *scoping* and *life-time*.

Comment: Should I declare it `static`? Or is there any other better method?

Comment: Return `res` *by value*.

Comment: But `res` is a `valarray`. I need a user defined array returned.

Comment: @IbrahimYousaf _"I need a user defined array returned."_ How is that function used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a variable with automatic [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration), meaning that it will be destroyed right when the function exits. `e` is a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), so accessing it is undefined behavior. You can return a `std::valarray` instead.

```
std::valarray<int> subtract(int* lastline, int* firstline){
    // Stuff
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I was returning the pointer to convert the `valarray` to a basic array. By returning the value, I won't be able to achieve that.

Comment: @IbrahimYousaf Return by value then get *another* pointer to it.

Comment: Great! Thank you.
Since the learned fellows have taken down my reputation for amusement, I can't upvote your comment.

Comment: @IbrahimYousaf But hey, they downvoted you not for amusement. It's because they thought your question was too trivial. Indeed one about returning a pointer to a local variable is trivial (I agree).

Comment: True, but my initial problem was looking for a method to convert `valarray` to a basic array.

Comment: @IbrahimYousaf What about dynamic allocation with `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161744/discussion-between-ibrahim-yousaf-and-ibug).